# How can I create a GPX file from a .csv using writeOGR that preserves more attributes besides 'ele'. I need to include a timestamp for each point

Tags: r, csv, gpx, spatial-data-frame

I have a csv file of locations and attributes (it's in a csv file because it was post-corrected from a TopCon GPS unit using NRCAN's PPP service).

I have columns for `lat`, `lon`, `ele` and `time`. I am now trying to make a GPX file from this csv. I am able to make a GPX but just cannot figure out how to preserve more attributes than just 'ele' for each point. I really need points to also have a time stamp. I have tried using `GPS_USE_EXTENSIONS=YES` but it appears to make no difference whatsoever to my output. I have also tried writing the GPX as a track, thinking it might then 'look' for a timestamp, with no success.

This is what my dataframe (df) looks like:

```
coordinates            ele          time
(-94.98907, 74.71942)  67.276       2014-07-11T01:46:36Z
(-94.98907, 74.71942)  67.282       2014-07-11T01:46:36Z
```

The weird looking time format is because that is what I eventually need it to look like in the GPX file.

Happy to provide the rest of the code (getting the spatial dataframe etc) if it's helpful.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hey, welcome to StackOverflow. While you described making a GPX file, could you show what code you used to do so?

Comment: I don't understand, are you parsing this data frame yourself or are you using a package? Also if you could copy the output of `dput(head(df))`, that would help

Comment: Please be more reactive.